# Sum of returned list: Error: invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Tags: r, list, return, return-value

For my script I'm returning a bunch of variables in R, and after splitting up my script in more functions I need to return some lists, along with other data.

I know I can return multiple values by `c(value1, value2)`. But how can I do this when one of the items returned is actually a list?
I'm returning listOne, however it looks like the data type gets changed when returning. 
How can I get return the list without changing its type?

Here's an example:

```
  B <- function(){
   listOne <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
   testString <- "Test"
   return(list(listOne, testString))
 }
  returnlist <- B()
```

Assigning the variables according to the returned list:

```
  copy.listOne <- returnlist# [1]
  copy.testString <- returnlist[2]
```

Expected output:

```
  listOne <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
  print(sum(listOne))
# [1] 21
```

Actual output:

```
  print(sum(copy.listOne))
Error in print(sum(copy.listOne)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'print': Error in sum(copy.listOne) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

Comment: use `[[`, `returnlist[[1]]`, you should also edit the previous question...

Comment: @LyzandeR Thanks! that did the trick, if you want to write it as answer I'll accept it! I have actually deleted the other question, I had already attempted to use `list` before, but then I realised it was because of different data types. That's why I decided to delete the old question and rewrite it completely. hope it was the right course of action.

Comment: Thanks @Bas . Usually you just need to edit your previous question instead of deleting it and then posting a new one. But it's fine for now :) . I ll post as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are working with lists you need to use `[[` in order to subset them. In your case when you create the function as follows

```
  B <- function(){
   listOne <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
   testString <- "Test"
   return(list(listOne, testString))
 }
  returnlist <- B()
```

you then need to use `[[` in order to access the elements of that list.

As you can see below all work now properly:

```
> returnlist[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
> returnlist[[2]]
[1] "Test"
> sum(returnlist[[1]])
[1] 21
```